# Why the line not cut across the data?

Tags: python, graph, linear-regression, train-test-split

I using linear regression model to predict my data.
[Orig Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQn9D.png)

When I using sns plot; I able to see the line cut's thru to all the data point.
[Using snsborn.lmplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooQTI.png)

But when I using train_test_split function:
The coeff & interc as below :
Weight =  [0.20504568]
Intercept = -1.0383656275693958

But graph is totally out
[graph using train test split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efySj.png)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My bad... i using the wrong X value for the line graph.